# why are attributes passed as strings in getattr()?

Tags: python

When printing the value of a variable, you don't add quotations around the variable but when using the getattr() function to access the value of an attribute you pass it as a string. Is there a reason for this or is it something I just have to remember?

Comment: If you didn't pass it as a string, how would it know what attribute you want?

Comment: If you ever pass a string literal to `getattr`, you're using it wrong - `getattr(thing, 'attrname')` is just a slow and clunky way to write `thing.attrname`. The usefulness of `getattr` comes from being able to pass in strings determined at runtime, like `getattr(thing, some_var_holding_a_string)`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Not necessarily; an attribute name does not have to be a valid identifier, which is a requirement for using dotted access. You could, for example, do something like `setattr(x, 'if', 1)`, then use `getattr(x, 'if')` to retrieve the value, where `x.if` would be a syntax error. (Whether such attribute names are a good idea is another matter.)

Comment: The *purpose* of `getattr` is to let you use strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the purpose of `getattr`. That way you can access attributes dynamically, based on a string stored in memory.

Example scenario:

```
user_provided_input = input()

getattr(some_object, user_provided_input + "dummy")
```

If the user typed "justa" this would be exactly the same as:

```
some_object.justadummy
```

You can also use strings that usually would cause a syntax error or some other kind of error if used as a string literal as well:

```
>>> setattr(some_object, ".", "dummyvalue")
>>> getattr(some_object, ".")
'dummyvalue'
>>> some_object..
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    some_object..
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```